# Probability for a biased die

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I'm having problems trying to solve this question:

We have a single biased die. The probability of getting an even number as a result is three times the probability of getting an odd number. 
In the limit of an infinite number of trials, what is the probability of getting as result an even number MORE than half the times?

My intuition tells me that this probability is equal to 1, but I can't find  a way to prove this rigorously.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It follows from the weak law of large numbers; you can prove it using Chebyshev inequality, the same way WLLN is proven.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer @kludg

Answer (score 0):

In this case also the Strong Law of Large Numbers is attained: so by definition

$$\mathbb{P}[\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_i X_i}{n}=\frac {3}{4}]=1$$

Comment: thanks you for the answer!